# Swift 3 Instance member type

Tags: ios, swift

I have a func saveNotes() which is a sub-class of NSObject

**Note.swift file**

```
func saveNotes() {
        var aDictionaries:[NSDictionary] = []
        for i:Int in 0 ..< allNotes.count {
            aDictionaries.append(allNotes[i].dictionary())
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(aDictionaries, forKey: kAllNotes)
    }
```

When I try to run my project I get an error "Instance member 'saveNotes' cannot be used on type 'Note'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead.

**code from MasterViewControler.swift**

```
import UIKit 
import Foundation


class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var objects = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        Note.loadNotes()
        print("allNotes: \(allNotes)")
        var n:Note = Note()
        Note.saveNotes()
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: `n.saveNotes()` instead.

Comment: Try to make `saveNotes()` as `static` function, also as @luk2302 suggest is good

Comment: 1. How can a function be a subclass of `NSObject`? That makes no sense. 2. This is Swift, generally you don't use `NSObject`. 3. Do not use `NS[Mutable]Dictionary` or `NS[Mutable]Array`. Use native Swift dictionaries and arrays.

Comment: Noted.  Thank you Luk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error of:

> Instance member 'saveNotes' cannot be used on type 'Note'; did you
>   mean to use a value of this type instead.

is shown by the compiler because you are trying to call a *non-instance method* directly from the class.

Thus, you would have 2 approaches:

**First**: Use the declared `n` instance to call the `saveNotes()` function:

```
Note.loadNotes()
print("allNotes: \(allNotes)")
let n:Note = Note()
n.saveNotes()
```

**Second**: if you are aiming to call `saveNotes()` directly from `Note` class, then it should be declared as *`static`* method:

```
static func saveNotes() { ... }
```

For more information, you could check [Swift Documentation - Method](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html) ("Type Methods" section).